# Wide angle picture with react-native-vision-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am attempting to capture wide-angle photos using the `react-native-vision-camera` library.

```js
    import { Camera, useCameraDevice } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
    
    const device = useCameraDevice('back');
    
    <Camera
      ref={cameraRef}
      style={styles.cameraContainer}
      device={device}
      autoFocus={'off'}
      autoFocusPointOfInterest={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
      isActive={true}
      enableZoomGesture={true}
      zoom={0}
    />
```

Despite setting the `zoom to 0`, the resulting image is not as wide as desired. Additionally, enabling `pinch-to-zoom` gestures and zooming out to the maximum does not achieve the desired wide-angle effect. When comparing to the iPhone camera app, the image can be pinched much wider.